# HackerRank - Filter huge list for elements that occur more than a given number of times

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to solve [this problem on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/filter-elements/problem), which basically requires the solution to read an input like this (comments are mine)

```
3                      # the number of cases, each of which consists of a pair of lines below
9 2                    # case 1, the two numbers are N and K
4 5 2 5 4 3 1 3 4      # case 1, the N numbers; filter out those that occur less than K times
9 4                    # case 2
4 5 2 5 4 3 1 3 4      # case 2
10 2                   # case 3
5 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5    # case 3
```

and the desired output is

```
4 5 3
-1
5 4 3 2 1
```

where the second line signifies that there's no number in case 2 which occurs 4 times or more, first and third lines list those elemnts of cases 1 and 3 which all occur the prescribed number of times or more (in this case the threshold is 2 for both case 1 and case 2).

I came up with an algorithmically correct solution, but apparently it has poor performance, as it fails for timeout on [this input](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/2509/input04.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV&Expires=1599333689&Signature=eCWU%2B9EbnHuAjUOujBuSxKqipug%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) ([expected output](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/2509/output04.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV&Expires=1599333876&Signature=7umJdsH0BR3egosMBWSXyZztTw8%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain))

```hs
import Control.Monad (liftM2)
import Data.List (sort,groupBy)
import Data.List (foldl')
main :: IO()
main = do
  nCasesStr <- getLine
  let nCase = read nCasesStr :: Int
  sequence_ $ replicate nCase $ do
    firstLine <- getLine
    secondLine <- getLine
    let [_,k] = asInts $ firstLine
    let list  = asInts $ secondLine      -- LINE A
    let outList = processList k list
    if null outList
      then putStr $ show (-1)
      else mapM_ (putStr . (++" ") . show) outList -- LINE B
    putStrLn ""
    where
      asInt :: String -> Int
      asInt s = read s :: Int
      asInts :: String -> [Int]
      asInts = map asInt . words

processList :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
processList k = map fst . filter ((>= k) . snd) . foldl' step []
  where
    step acc@((n,c):ac) val
      | n == val = (n,c + 1):ac
      | otherwise = (n,c):step ac val
    step _ val = [(val,1)]
```

I'm especially worried about the lines marked as `-- LINE A` ad `-- LINE B`: they both traverse the full long input and output lines respectively; then the `processList` function traverses the input too. Traversing the input only once while spitting out output, however, would not change the BigO complexity, but just reduce it by a factor of 3, am I right?

As regards the `processList` function, I'm quite happy I had the idea of using a fold (the three of them don't seem to have a consistent difference in performances, as regards the bulk test cases), but maybe I've chosen the wrong `step`ping function?

Or maybe folding is not the right tool in this case?

Comment: I have moved this question of mine from StackOverflow to here. Someone had left this comment: _Counting happens in O(n), and this per elements, so it makes it an O(n^2) algorithm. You might want to use a Map, and thus first calculate the number of occurences per element._

Comment: Algorithmic complexity is important to think about, in particular in a competitive programming context (which HackerRank is) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you already solved it, so good job! :)

I took the liberty to solve the challenge too, so I'll post my code below. I tried to make the code a bit more "functional", or less imperative, if you will: there is less logic in IO. It's also slightly shorter than yours, though that's not really a goal. I also used a number of techniques and library functions that you could have used, but didn't; using them all is not necessarily what you want, but I wanted to showcase them nevertheless.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
import Control.Monad
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let readInts = map read . words <$> getLine
    [numCases] <- readInts
    cases <- sequence $ replicate numCases
                            (processCase <$> fmap (!!1) readInts
                                         <*> readInts)
    forM_ cases $ \case [] -> putStrLn "-1"
                        l  -> putStrLn (intercalate " " (map show l))
  where
    processCase :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
    processCase k l =
        let groups = [head g | g <- group (sort l), length g >= k]
            order = foldr (uncurry (Map.insertWith const))
                          mempty (zip l [0::Int ..])
        in sortOn (order Map.!) groups
```

In my subjective opinion, this is somewhat "cleaner", whatever that may mean. But make your own judgement, and most important is that you solved it. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the suggestion I got in the comment is enough to pass the HR test:

```hs
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Data.List (foldl', nub)
import qualified Data.Map as M

main :: IO()
main = do
  nCasesStr <- getLine
  let nCase = read nCasesStr :: Int
  sequence_ $ replicate nCase $ do
    k    <- (str2int. last . words) <$> getLine
    list <-    map str2int . words  <$> getLine
    let outList = processList k list
    if null outList
      then putStr $ show (-1)
      else mapM_ (putStr . (++" ") . show) outList
    putStrLn ""
    where
      str2int = read :: String -> Int

processList :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
processList k = nub . (filter <$> (flip (\x -> (k <=) . fromJust . M.lookup x . list2map)) <*> id)
  where
    list2map = foldl' step M.empty
    step map num = M.insertWith (+) num 1 map
```